# REST API to Login to Google Platform using Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

I have created a service account on Google Cloud Platform. I am using a standalone Java program which uses GCP Java Client API to get the Authentication Token ID by taking service account JSON file. By using the Token ID, I can create a compute instance.

I don't want to use Java API or gcloud tool, is there a REST API exists which takes required details and return Token ID?

I went through the GCP documentation and could not find any details for the authentication and authorization through REST using Service Account.

Comment: I also want the REST API to retrieve access token using service account keys. Have you found out any solutions for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created a service account on Google Cloud Platform. I am using
>   a standalone Java program which uses GCP Java Client API to get the
>   Authentication Token ID by taking service account JSON file. By using
>   the Token ID, I can create a compute instance.

Using a service account is the correct and recommended method to authenticate and authorize software applications.

Note. The assumption here is that the software application is running on your systems under your control. If instead you are installing software on a user's desktop or system not under your control, then you would use Google OAuth 2.0 (Google Accounts) to obtain User Credentials to authorize your application.

Another method is to issue short-lived temporary credentials from a service account credential that are time limited. These short-lived credentials are created on your server and then handed to the client.

> I don't want to use Java API or gcloud tool, is there a REST API
>   exists which takes required details and return Token ID?

You have the classic "Chicken or Egg" situation. You need credentials to authenticate and authorize otherwise anyone could create credentials. Google Service Account credentials provides this. To create service account credentials, use the Google Cloud Console or `gcloud` CLI to download the service account Json file.

> I went through the GCP documentation and could not find any details
>   for the authentication and authorization through REST using Service
>   Account.

This question is confusing. Do you want to use Service Account credentials to authorize your Google API calls OR do you want to call a Google API to obtain credentials?

In the first case, once you create service account credentials, they are used to authorize your API calls. You add the Access Token to the HTTP header when making API calls.

For the second case, use Google OAuth 2.0 to obtain credentials. Google OAuth 2.0 uses Google Accounts for authentication. This method provides you with an Access Token (just like a service account) and a Refresh Token and Client ID token. You will need to add the Google Accounts user identity to your Google Cloud IAM which provides for authorization (privileges).

Comment: Thanks John for the explanation. I have already created a service account from the GCP Console and downloaded the Private Key JSON file containing (type, project_id, private_key_id, private_key, client_email, client_id, auth_uri, token_uri, auth_provider_x509_cert_url and client_x509_cert_url).  Now, I want to create a Compute resource for which I am using the REST API. The header of the REST API needs "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN_ID>". Now I am using Java Client to generate the TOKEN_ID by specifying the private key file. I would like to know, if a REST API exists to get the TOKEN_ID?

Comment: By TOKEN_ID you mean AccessToken. All Google APIs require an Access Token. Close this question and create a new question "How do I create an Access Token from Service Account Credentials?".